# Manage config translations programmatically

Tags: 8, configuration

My module creates and manages some config_entities programmatically (ie. not through an EntityForm) in response to associated content entities being saved.

In order to handle multi-language content entities, I see two options:

- create one config entity and add translations for it
- create a unique config entity for each translation

The first seems cleaner - however, I don't see how to actually transparently manage translations for config entities. Translating an entity with the `config_translation` module appears to create a new entry in the `config` table with `collection = language.xx`, but I don't see how to access a translated entity explicitly (rather than it being automatically mapped by the site's interface language). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer from @Smartsheet eng is correct if you want to *load* and read a specific translation as a config entity, see also [How to progragrammatically get NodeType translated value in D8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263735/how-to-progragrammatically-get-nodetype-translated-value-in-d8/263807#263807).

However, changing them is different, because the config entity can't be saved like that, it doesn't understand what is a translation and what's not. It will just overwrite your default language with that data. See also https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2910353.

To actually manage a translation of a config entity, you have to directly interact with the config system, you can see how in \Drupal\config_translation\Form\ConfigTranslationFormBase::submitForm():

```
$config_translation = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguageConfigOverride($langcode, $config_name);

// Write the keys you want to translate on the config object.
$config_translation->save();
```

Comment: Note: `$config_translation->setData($config_entity->toArray());`  is how you get from config entity to config object.

Comment: That doesn't work for any entity type (field storages) and then you'd have everything in there, you must only add the translatable keys.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can see -- yes, this is possible but it's not as pretty as `$contentEntity->getTranslation($langcode);`. The full enchillada would be:

```
protected function getTranslatedConfigEntity(ConfigEntityInterface $configEntity, LanguageInterface $language) {
  $langcode = $language->id():
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityTypeInterface $configEntityType */
  $configEntityType = $configEntity->getEntityType();
  $name = $configEntityType->getConfigPrefix() . '.' . $configEntity->id();
  $translatedConfig = $this->languageManager->getLanguageConfigOverride($langcode, $name);
  $translatedConfig[$configEntity->getKeys('langcode')] = $langcode;
  $class = $configEntityType->getClass();
  return new $class($translatedConfig->get(), $configEntityType->id());
}
```

An alternative would be:

```
public function getTranslatedConfigEntity(ConfigEntityInterface $configEntity, LanguageInterface $language) {
  $currentLanguage = $this->languageManager->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
  $this->languageManager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);
  $translatedConfigEntity = $this->entityTypeManager
    ->getStorage($configEntity->getEntityTypeId())
    ->load($configEntity->id());
  $this->languageManager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($currentLanguage);
  return $translatedConfigEntity;
}
```

Comment: Just to mention, not all config entities can be translated with this approach. For example, webform entity defines its own translation logic.

Comment: My config is ImmutableConfig; how do i t get a specific translation of that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding translation from code (in my case update hook) should look something like:

```
$my_field_translation = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguageConfigOverride('de', 'field.field.node.my_conent_type.my_field_name');
$my_field_translation->set('label', 'German Label');
$my_field_translation->save();
```

To get exact name of config file ('field.field.node.my_conent_type.my_field_name') I added translation manually for field, exported config ("drush cex") and saw what config file was changed...