# How to progragrammatically get NodeType translated value in D8?

Tags: 8, nodes, entities, i18n-l10n

Fetching node translation

```
$node = Node::load($nid);
$node->getTitle(); // returns title in en(default language).
$translated_node = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($node, 'es');
$translated_node->getTitle(); // Returns translated title in es (spanish).
```

If we want to fetch the bundle's translation. The above approach doesn't work.

Kindly advise?

```
$article = $node->bundle();
$article->label(); // returns "Article".
$translated = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($article, 'es');
$translated->label(); // Also returns "Article".
```

Translation for bundles provided from `/admin/structure/types/manage/article/translate/es/edit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the config override language to the desired language:

```
  $language = $language_manager->getLanguage('es');
  $original_language = $language_manager->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
  $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);

  // Load the node type here.       

  $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($original_language);
```

Taken from `user_mail()`