# How to get translated field_storage_config

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, configuration

I need to programmatically set the translated values for several fields on a node. For that I would like to set their values in the fields field_storage_config. Adapted from another question's answer ([Manage config translations programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236510/manage-config-translations-programmatically)) I tried the following, but without success:

```
$origLang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
$lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguage($currentTranslationLanguageId);
$untranslatedStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_storage_config')->load("node.$tagsBaseFieldId");
$untranslatedValues = $untranslatedStorage->getSetting('allowed_values');
\Drupal::languageManager()->setConfigOverrideLanguage($lang);
$translatedStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_storage_config')->load("node.$tagsBaseFieldId");
```

I expected to get the field_storage_config of the override language that I set in the languageManager (different from the base language), but if I dump $untranslatedStorage and $translatedStorage after these commands, they are the same. $untranslatedStorage and $translatedStorage are the same object. How is this possible and how can I programmatically set the translations for my field(s).
It is a text list field (the one that translates to a selectbox in the UI).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is this possible and how can I programmatically set the
>   translations for my field(s)?

You can load language overrides with [ConfigurableLanguageManager::getLanguageConfigOverride](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21src%21ConfigurableLanguageManager.php/function/ConfigurableLanguageManager%3A%3AgetLanguageConfigOverride/8.7.x), set values and save:

```
\Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguageConfigOverride('fr', 'field.storage.node.field_example')
  ->set($key, $value)
  ->save();
```

Comment: This works, finally. Thanks a lot!