# Get Translated Field Label for Entity

Tags: 9

I have a field I have translated. But I can not figure out how to get that translated field label programmatically. I've found a few posts on here, but none of them work for me.

Pretty easy to get the default field label:

```
$fieldDefinition = $model->get($field)->getFieldDefinition();
$fieldLabel = $fieldDefinition->getLabel();
```

Does anyone know a way to get that in 2022?

I thought the answer might lie in here somewhere, but so far no luck. Just trying to grab the spanish translation right now...

```
$language_manager = \Drupal::languageManager();

$language = $language_manager->getLanguage('es');
$original_language = $language_manager->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
$language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Config translation works in the background as override. So you don't need to do anything.

Unless have a very specific use cases, like sending an email in a different language. Then you can change the config override language, like the code you've shown so far, and reset it after you've sent the email:

```
use Drupal\Core\Field\Entity\BaseFieldOverride;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;

...

$language_manager = \Drupal::languageManager();

$language = $language_manager->getLanguage('es');
$original_language = $language_manager->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
$language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);

// load a new field definition object instead of referencing the one stored in the entity
// in case of a translated base field:
$field_definition = BaseFieldOverride::loadByName($entity->getEntityTypeId(), $entity->bundle(), $field_name);
// in case of a translated configured field:
$field_definition = FieldConfig::loadByName($entity->getEntityTypeId(), $entity->bundle(), $field_name);

$field_label = $field_definition->getLabel();

$language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($original_language);
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm creating a spec chart component. So that's created with code, and not just a rendered field. Something must not be clicking. The code I have doesn't get the translated field label. This `$fieldDefinition->getLabel()` is always the same - english. I wish it was easy like `$fieldDefinition->getTranslation('es')->getLabel()` but obviously that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you have a translation stored in the config? See this topic how to get and set language overrides on a lower level: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282995/how-to-get-translated-field-storage-config. It could also help to export the config and check the config names and the language overrides (exported to sub directories).

Comment: I do see it in when I export the config. It's in there. But still, no matter what I do, it's in english. My `$fieldDefinition` which is `Drupal\Core\Field\Entity\BaseFieldOverride` always shows the `langcode  = "en"`. I just don't know where my disconnect is or what I'm not understanding. I really appreciate the help. I keep thinking something is going to click. It's super easy getting the field value though `$model->getTranslation($lang)->get($field)->getString()`.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit confusing. When loading a config with a language override the langcode is still the original language of the config object while the config values inside of the object are translated.

Comment: The field definition you get from the entity seems to be cached in memory. I edit the answer how to load the object in a different way.