# Where do you put install config translations?

Tags: i18n-l10n, configuration

I have a Drupal 9 site. When I export site config (drush cex) I get config/sync dir with settings and inside it I have i.e. language/de where translation config is stored. So translations are in config/sync/language/de (for German i.e.).

Where should go those translation files for a module?
Like, for module I have config/install where my install files are. Should I have there something like:
config/install/language/de  for translation files or...?

Comment: Interesting question. Don't know if this is good practice, but it should work. You probably won't find many examples, though. Most modules ship translations via .po files.

Comment: I didn't find any example so probably it's not good practice. I agree. I wonder why that inconsistency exists. :/

Comment: At end I added translation from code, explained here:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/314792/50525